# nightmarejs scrape multiple Elements with querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, nightmare

I'm trying to scrape some informations from an instagram profile page with nightmarejs (a phantomjs derivate using electron as a browser).

The goal is to get the alt tags of all images on the profile (for examples sake I focus only on the images before the "show more" button)

```js
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });

nightmare
  .goto('https://www.instagram.com/ackerfestival/')
  .evaluate(function () {
    let array = [...document.querySelectorAll('._icyx7')];
    return array.length;
  })
  .end()
  .then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Search failed:', error);
  });
```

This example works, the array has a length of 12. The electron browser opens and closes, so everything is fine. But if I change the return to just the array, the electron browser never closes and I don't get a console.log.

What am I doing wrong? I want to get all informations from the images in an Array or Object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you're hitting is `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a `NodeList` of `DOMElement`s.  Those two object types do not serialize well, and the return value from `.evaluate()` has to serialize across the IPC boundary - I'm betting you're getting an empty array on the other side of your `.evaluate()` call?

The easiest answer here is to map out what, specifically, you want from the `NodeList`.  From the hip, something like the following should get the idea across:

```
.evaluate(function(){
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('._icyx7')).map(element => element.innerText);
})
.then((innerTexts) => {
  // ... do something with the inner texts of each element
})
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution for most people. However, if you have to do many extractions/tests/etc on the data, a totally different approach that is working well for me is to simply return `return document.body.innerHTML` and then on the node side, instantiate a jsdom and/or jquery object. At that point, interacting with the virtual dom is trivial.